# C++/Qt download file in sync

Tags: c++, qt, networking

I want to achieve to download a file in a separate thread and store that file,
but I was not able to find an appropriate way to achieve this without evil delay (quite frequent download of small files, so signal+slots are too slow).
What I want to achieve:
(Pseudo Code)

```
request file;
wait for download finishing, timeout or error;
save downloaded file;
```

I'd prefer an example with QNetworkAccessManager if possible.
Thanks for any tipp.

Edit: Just to be clear, I want signal and slots not because of design aswell as the lack of speed.

Edit2: This download is only about the download file in sync part, threading is no problem.
The problem is that QT does not provide an api for doing that and I am not keen on hotspinning wait.

Edit3: Example code like it should work, but does not:

```
QNetworkAccessManager net;
QNetworkReply *re (net.get( QNetworkRequest( QUrl( Qstring("www.blah.org/key") ) ) ));
if (re->waitForReadyRead(-1)) //! @bug this does not work as supposed, waitForRead returns false and returns INSTANTLY!!
    qDebug() << "ReadyRead yeha!!!";
if (re->error()) {
    qDebug() << "Can't download" << re->url().toString()
            << ":" << re->errorString();
} else {
    img->load(re->readAll());
    qDebug() << "Savin IMG";
}
delete re;
```

Comment: Seems that without local event loop your "re" doesn't even know that it is finished. I've met similar problem. P.S. Do not delete QNetworkReply directly, use "deleteLater".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed something similar but for different reasons. Since QHttp and QNetworkAccessManager are both async what you could do is use a separate event loop, a full example based on QHttp can be found [here](http://www.erata.net/qt-boost/synchronous-http-request/). It shouldn't be too difficult to modify it for QNetworkAccessManager.

It's worth mentioning that your impression that signals/slots are "slow" is probably wrong. Have you actually profiled your code to determine this?

Whatever penalty you might be paying for signals/slots it's probably negligible when looking at the amount of time a single file download takes. More so, it's very "non Qt" to do things this way. These classes were designed like this for a reason.

At the end of the day **if** you are indeed suffering from signals/slots (which is again, doubtful), I would recommend not to use Qt for this particular task, maybe plain old C sockets are a better idea (or a thin wrapper around them to save the error handling which might require some extra work).

Comment: Well I hoped not having to use exec() in the parallel thread.
You got me an idea :-D thank you

Comment: ok after 3hours of searching I stumbbled accross this:
http://wiki.qtcentre.org/index.php?title=Keeping_the_GUI_Responsive
and it suggests the same way you suggested me, and I did it that way and it works. Thank you. You solved it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sync Network access is a bad idea because it makes bad UI experience. Besides what you think is a bug is not a bug. It is just wrongly documented.

Comment: Syncing these is perfectly fine for testing tools, Unit tests and even server logic / something that just don't neet to respond in real time.