# Why am I unable to download a file using this code

Tags: c++, qt, download

I'm working on a school project and since many weeks I try to adapt [this code](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Download_Data_from_URL), but it returns me an empty QByteArray. I really need this code, cause my whole project is based on this code.

Here is my code :

```
namespace Pixmap {
static QByteArray *bitmap;

QPixmap downloadPixmap(const QUrl &url);
QPixmap downloadPixmap(const QString &url);
}

QPixmap Pixmap::downloadPixmap(QUrl const& url)
{
QNetworkAccessManager access_manager;
QNetworkReply *reply = access_manager.get(
            QNetworkRequest(url)
            );
QPixmap pix;
bitmap = &reply->readAll();
reply->close();
if (/*!bitmap->isNull() && */ !reply->readAll().isNull()) {
    pix.loadFromData(*bitmap);
    return pix;
} else {
    // Apparemment aux tests 1 et 2 pas d'erreurs.
    qDebug("Damned");
    return QPixmap();
}
}

QPixmap Pixmap::downloadPixmap(QString const& url)
{
    return downloadPixmap(QUrl(url));
}
```

I thought the solution was to use a static variable to receive data's reply, but it wasn't.

Could you give some advice, please.

I'm developping on Windows currently with Qt 5.3.

Thank you all.

Edit 1:
So I merged Nejat's second solution with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663655/c-qt-download-file-in-sync).

The result is not concluding. The debugger advices me HTTP protocol is not supported.

```
Can't download "http://127.0.0.1/Acompte/MCD_Ordi.jpg" : "Protocol type not supported"

if (reply->waitForReadyRead(-1)) //! @bug this does not work as supposed, waitForRead returns false and returns INSTANTLY!!
    qDebug() << "ReadyRead yeha!!!";
if (reply->error()) {
    qDebug() << "Can't download" << reply->url().toString()
            << ":" << reply->errorString();
} else {
    bitmap = reply->readAll();
    qDebug() << "Saving IMG";
}
```

What does the problem come from according to you ? I'm still new to Qt Widgets and I don't master QObject::connect.

Edit 2:
The URL is local, there it is : 127.0.0.1/Acompte/MCD_Ordi.jpg I am able to view it with my web browser, but not within my application. So I don't see what's the problem.

Now I try, it returns the message that HTTP protocol is not supported.

Comment: You have to wait between sending the GET request and reading the data in the response, but you don't.

Comment: Hi Vahancho, it would be sweet from you to explain this by showing an example ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You must set the finished signal of your access_manager

```
connect(access_manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
this, SLOT(myFunctionToHandleReply(QNetworkReply *)));
```

And your myFunctionToHandleReply must handle the reply:

```
void MyApp::myFunctionToHandleReply(QNetworkReply *reply) {
    QByteArray data = reply->readAll();
}
```

The documentation with the signals of QNetworkAccessManager: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it in an asynchronous way by connecting the `finished` signal of the `QNetworkAccessManager` to a slot :

```
connect(&access_manager,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this,SLOT(onFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
```

And read data there :

```
void onFinished(QNetworkReply* reply)
{

   if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
   {
       QByteArray bts = reply->readAll();

       ...
   }
}
```

You can also use an event loop to wait until the reply is finished and then read the available bytes :

```
QNetworkAccessManager access_manager;

QNetworkReply *reply = access_manager.get(QNetworkRequest(url));

QEventLoop loop;
connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
connect(reply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
loop.exec();

QByteArray bts = reply->readAll();
...
```

Comment: I went for the Event loop. Here is what my compiler (Visual C++ 2013) returns : QObject::connect: No such signal QNetworkReplyHttpImpl::error() in ..\horaires_de_commerces\pixmap.cpp:12
Damned

Comment: @SteveHuguenin You should also provide the argument type of `error` signal. See the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks ! Strange, Qt Creator doesn't show parameters to enter.

Answer (score 0):

So I merged Nejat's second solution with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663655/c-qt-download-file-in-sync).

The result is not concluding. The debugger advices me HTTP protocol is not supported.

```
Can't download "http://127.0.0.1/Acompte/MCD_Ordi.jpg" : "Protocol type not supported"

if (reply->waitForReadyRead(-1)) //! @bug this does not work as supposed, waitForRead returns false and returns INSTANTLY!!
    qDebug() << "ReadyRead yeha!!!";
if (reply->error()) {
    qDebug() << "Can't download" << reply->url().toString()
            << ":" << reply->errorString();
} else {
    bitmap = reply->readAll();
    qDebug() << "Saving IMG";
}
```

What does the problem come from according to you ? I'm still new to Qt Widgets and I don't master QObject::connect.

Edit :
This request is blocked by a hidden proxy at work.

Plus be aware, this code will not create a memory leak :

```
QEventLoop *loop = new QEventLoop;
QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), loop, SLOT(quit()));
QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)), loop, SLOT(quit()));
loop->exec();
```

You don't need to delete QObject derived objects.

Comment: This is not an answer. You should edit your question or ask a new one if there is an other problem.

Comment: @Nejat Your comment is right, but unfortunately I'm still unable to download any files by using Qt and his QNetworkReply...

Comment: What's that address. Are you trying to download from your local host? Do you have a web server?

Comment: That's http://127.0.0.1/Acompte/MCD_Ordi.jpg. I am able to view it with my web browser. So I don't see what's the problem.